# Does the Android emulator generate some sort of log file I can access if it crashes?

Tags: android-emulator, logging

Let's say I am working with the Android emulator, and get it to run one of my custom images/custom kernels, and it gets stuck in a boot-loop or crashes after a little while in booting up, does it produce a log file that I can look through?  And if so, where does it store this "boot" log?  (most likely somewhere in the Android build tree)

Comment: you could also just do an 'adb logcat' and start your instance to see what happens

Comment: Yeah but it just says <waiting for device>.  And if the emulator is simulating the phone crashing, does the emulator itself produce any log messages?

Comment: Well, the emulator itself is just fine. Simulating phone crashes and reboot loops is just as indifferent to it as normal operation

Comment: There are some questions about it on Stackoverflow ([google search](https://www.google.de/search?q='adb+logcat'+emulator+site:stackoverflow.com+boot+crash)), it's more dev related though but there are a number of hits. Most probably it has to do something with either permissions for adb or your build is not adb enabled

Answer (score 2):

### kernel panic

When a kernel panic occurs all user space programs are immediately stopped, preventing a user from detecting the cause of the panic: `logcat`; `dmesg` and `/proc/kmsg` will do you no good.

You can still check the `/data/dontpanic/` folder for any files present, like:

`apanic_console` or `apanic_threads`

---

### kernel boot

Method of logging kernel messages:

1. invoke "dmesg":

   - See it as it happens:

     ```
     # adb shell dmesg
     ```
   - Direct to a file on your sdcard and see it later

     ```
     # adb shell dmesg >/mnt/sdcard/dmesg.txt
     ```
2. "tail" the kernel if "syslogd" and `/var` are available:

   ```
   # adb shell cat /proc/kmsg
   ```
3. dump the kernel file `/proc/kmsg`:

   ```
   # adb shell cat /proc/kmsg
   ```

**Note:** You may need to issue `su` to gain permissions over some files if you're stuck with an error message. Alternatively, removing `shell` from the command will execute it on the computer side, not on the phone.

---

### References

- Stackoverflow [answer from eldarerathis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469188/352449) to "Can I get logcat logs after phone reboots?"
- BootLoader [How to get kernel messages from Android?](http://bootloader.wikidot.com/linux:android:kmsg)
- flashmyandroid [How to get logcat and dmesg outputs for trouble shooting !](http://www.flashmyandroid.com/forum/showthread.php?805-How-to-get-logcat-and-dmesg-outputs-for-trouble-shooting-!&s=2d29a743a3352997e9084c3566a2cb67&p=5271&viewfull=1#post5271)
- Stackoverflow [Android: How to get kernel logs after kernel panic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9682306/352449)
- Stackoverflow [Shutdown Log in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6071547/352449)

Comment: This is great information (as well as the posts you reference).  However, it seems there's one massive wall every developer is going to run into:  what about a BOOT-LOOP?

You're phone (or emulator) crashes as it boots up with your installed image, and keeps trying to reboot, but keeps crashing.  How do you get kernel messages or any kind of log to figure out how far the phone gets?

Comment: @9exceptionThrower9 All comes down to the cause! you may check for the folder `/data/dontpanic/` for logs concerning the kernel failure or act according to instructions provided by eldarerathis (first link on the references section).

Comment: @9exceptionThrower9 Keep in mind that this type of issues are prone to be very specific, since they depend on many variables. Ain't easy to have a bulletproof solution :)