# How can I see bootloader stdout debugging messages?

Tags: bootloader, logging

I'm trying to understand the mechanisms of the Android bootloader.
The source code for this is here:
https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/recovery.cpp?repo=platform--bootable--recovery

I want to see the messages which are printed by LOGE(stdout, "message").
ADB is not yet active at this time so I can't use logcat or the shell on the device. Is there a way to set up anything on the device so I can write the messages to a logfile or the display of the device? I don't want to install a different bootloader, I would like to see the default bootloader "in action".

I'm using a rooted HTC Desire with S-OFF. Linux and Windows are available, communication to the device is possible via USB and WLAN.
Other suggestions posted in this forum did not help (like [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26463/android-debugging-boot-loops-is-there-any-way-to-get-a-log-of-information-witho), if I add the suggested lines it just boots up normally. Or [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26123/android-boot-up-messages-for-debugging), since I cannot use ADB).

Any help is very appreciated.

Best regards

Brandon